# Spring Boot with JPA/Hibernate: Apply db fixture without using FlyWay

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, flyway, spring-boot-3

We have Spring Boot 3, JPA/Hibernate, and MySQL 8.

We need to have a similar functionality as FlyWay for DB fixtures/migration scripts in our project.

For various reasons, we can not use the tools provided or supported by spring boot auto configuration like FlyWay and we need to implement this feature in-house. We also can not use the basic schema initialization method provided by Spring Boot including these: `schema.sql`, `import.sql`, and `data.sql` so please do not mention these methods. They were tried and not suitable for our team.

We have to have `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate`, we need to apply our db fixture before JPA/Hibernate wants to validate the entities against the db. We also have many stored procedures and we need to apply the changes on them as well.

We have this folder structure under the resource folder:

```
- resources
    - db
        - fixtures
            - 001-CPT-xxxx-changes.sql
            - 002-CPT-xxxx-changes.sql
            - 003-CPT-xxxx-changes.sql
        - stored-procedures 
            - 001-CPT-xxxx-sp_get_user_detail.sql
            - 002-CPT-xxxx-sp_get_something.sql
```

Now, we want to imitate the FlyWay by overriding/providing a bean so Spring Boot calls that before initializing the JPA Entity Manager. Also, this bean should get executed after the `datasource` or `jdbctemplate` initialization so we can have access to the DB.

I think that we should extend this class `AbstractBeansOfTypeDatabaseInitializerDetector` and somehow inject our bean/code into the database initialization process.

If we can find a way to execute our code before the EntityManager initialization by hibernate, then we can read the folder in the resource and execute our sql scripts one by one. We have a table to keep track of the executed ones and only execute those that are new or their size/modified date have been changed.

Thanks in advance.